# Angular Doc Controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsdoc

So I am currently am splitting my files; controllers, services & directives etc. effectively I have something like below

```
/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name application
 * @description
 * Main app controller.
 */
angular.module('application')
    /**
     * @ngdoc object
     * @name application.AppCtrl
     * @requires  $scope
     * @description
     * Hello App controller
     */
    .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'Hello from AppCtrl';
        $scope.updateMessage = function (msg) {
            $scope.message = msg;
        };
    });
```

What is being generated looks pretty much fine and right however, the overview part (application) doesn't seem to know or link to application.AppCtrl is it possible / how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're missing the `[]` after `'application'` angular is trying to retrieve the module application, does not exist (in your provided example). Passing an array as the second parameter creates the module, whereas just passing the module name with no array retrieves it.

```
/**
     * @ngdoc overview
     * @name application
     * @description
     * Main app controller.
     */
    angular.module('application',[])//pass an array as the second parameter
        /**
         * @ngdoc object
         * @name application.AppCtrl
         * @requires  $scope
         * @description
         * Hello App controller
         */
        .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.message = 'Hello from AppCtrl';
            $scope.updateMessage = function (msg) {
                $scope.message = msg;
            };
        });
```